# How to hide a Composite in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I created a Composite (SWT)  with two objects: Label and Text.

In some cases I don't want to see these widgets. When I press a button I want to hide the composite.

Do I have option to hide the composite so it won't hold place on the screen? (I don't want to see empty rows, I have other objects beside them)

How I can do it?

```
    Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 2;

Label label = new Label(comp , SWT.BORDER);
label.setText("This is a label:");
label.setToolTipText("This is the tooltip of this label");

Text text = new Text(comp , SWT.NONE);
text.setText("This is the text in the text widget");
text.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
text.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`dispose()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/ntopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.html#dispose%28%29) method to remove the `Composite`.
But then you have to create the `Composite` again if you want to show it again.

Edit:

Well or just use the solution Baz posted.
This is a better way...

Comment: Hiding is very different paradigm than disposing, especially for more complicated widgets that may have other children, etc. This should not be recommended.